# Metas OG Facebook: Dúvida

Tags: html, facebook, html-tags

Sempre que utilizo metas OG para compartilhamento do Facebook insiro elas na header e oculto as metas atuais de descrição e titulo do site.

**A dúvida é a seguinte:** as metas OG precisam estar na header do site? haverá algum problema se elas estiverem dentro da página dentro da tag body? Alguém já realizou testes com isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opá ! As metas tags foram criadas para serem usadas no cabeçalho (header) do HTML, já que elas e todo o conteúdo do header são invisíveis aos usuário final. Inserir elas no corpo, além de não agregar em nada na experiencia do usuário, também rompe com as regras dadas pela W3C.

Seja ela do Facebook ou não, ainda são meta tags, portanto deixe elas bem bonitinhas instanciadas no header do HTML.

Vide: [W3C School](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp)